# How to configure Apache APISIX with RSA & ECC dual certificates for the same domain?

Tags: apache-apisix

I am configuring a certificate for my domain on APISIX and I would like to know how to configure both types of certificates?

Answer (score 0):

APISIX supports loading multiple SSL certificates by TLS extension Server Name Indication (SNI). You can use the APISIX Admin API for [SSL](https://apisix.apache.org/docs/apisix/admin-api/#ssl-api) to create SSL objects in APISIX. And as the [documentation](https://apisix.apache.org/docs/apisix/certificate/#multiple-certificates-for-a-single-domain) quotes:

> #### Multiple certificates for a single domain:
>
> If you want to configure multiple certificates for a single domain, for
> instance, supporting both the
> [ECC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic-curve_cryptography)
> and RSA key-exchange algorithm, then just configure the extra certificates (the
> first certificate and private key should be still put in `cert` and `key`) and
> private keys by `certs` and `keys`.
>
> - `certs`: PEM-encoded certificate array.
> - `keys`: PEM-encoded private key array.
>
> `APISIX` will pair the certificate and private key with the same indices as an SSL key
> pair. So the length of `certs` and `keys` must be the same.

So to configure Apache APISIX with RSA & ECC dual certificates for the same domain, you would have to do something like this:

```bash
curl -X PUT "127.0.0.1:9180/apisix/admin/ssls/1" \
-H 'X-API-KEY: edd1c9f034335f136f87ad84b625c8f1' -d 
'{
    "cert": "certificate",
    "key": "key",
    "snis": [...],
    "certs": [...], <- extra certificates
    "keys": [...],  <- extra keys
}'
```